# I/O performance of multiple JVM (Windows 7 affected, Linux works)

Tags: performance, io, jvm, nested

I have a program that creates a file of about 50MB size. During the process the program frequently rewrites sections of the file and  forces the changes to disk (in the order of 100 times). It uses a FileChannel and direct ByteBuffers via fc.read(...), fc.write(...) and fc.force(...).

**New text:**

I have a better view on the problem now.
The problem appears to be that I use three different JVMs to modify a file (one creates it, two others (launched from the first) write to it). Every JVM closes the file properly before the next JVM is started.
The problem is that the cost of fc.write() to that file occasionally goes through the roof for the third JVM (in the order of 100 times the normal cost). That is, all write operations are equally slow, it is not just one that hang very long.
Interestingly, one way to help this is to insert delays (2 seconds) between the launching of JVMs. Without delay, writing is always slow, with delay, the writing is slow aboutr every second time or so.

I also found this [Stackoverflow: How to unmap a file from memory mapped using FileChannel in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972986/how-to-unmap-a-file-from-memory-mapped-using-filechannel-in-java) which describes a problem for mapped files, which I'm not using.

What I suspect might be going on:
Java does not completely release the file handle when I call close(). When the next JVM is started, Java (or Windows) recognizes concurrent access to that file and installes some expensive concurrency handler for that file, which makes writing expensive. 
Would that make sense?

The problem occurs on Windows 7 (Java 6 and 7, tested on two machines), but not under Linux (SuSE 11.3 64).

**Old text:**

The problem:
Starting the program from as a JUnit test harness from eclipse or from console works fine, it takes around 3 seconds.
Starting the program through an ant task (or through JUnit by kicking of a separate JVM using a ProcessBuilder) slows the program down to 70-80 seconds for the same task (factor 20-30).

Using -Xprof reveals that the usage of 'force0' and 'pwrite' goes through the roof from 34.1% (76+20 tics) to 97.3% (3587+2913+751 tics):
Fast run:

```
27.0%     0  +    76    sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.force0
 7.1%     0  +    20    sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.pwrite0
[..]
```

Slow run:

```
    Interpreted + native   Method                        
48.1%     0  +  3587    sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.pwrite0
39.1%     0  +  2913    sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.force0
[..]
     Stub + native   Method                        
10.1%     0  +   751    sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.pwrite0
[..]
```

GC and compilation are negligible.

More facts:

No other methods show a significant change in the -Xprof output.

- It's either fast or very slow, never something in-between.
- Memory is not a problem, all test machines have at least 8GB, the process uses <200MB
- rebooting the machine does not help
- switching of virus-scanners and similar stuff has no affect
- When the process is slow, there is virtually no CPU usage
- It is *never* slow when running it from a normal JVM
- It is pretty consistently slow when running it in a JVM that was started from the first JVM (via ProcessBuilder or as ant-task)
- All JVMs are exactly the same. I output System.getProperty("java.home") and the JVM options via  RuntimeMXBean RuntimemxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean(); List arguments = RuntimemxBean.getInputArguments();
- I tested it on two machines with Windows7 64bit, Java 7u2, Java 6u26 and JRockit, the hardware of the machines differs, though, but the results are very similar.
- I tested it also from outside Eclipse (command-line ant) but no difference there.
- The whole program is written by myself, all it does is reading and writing to/from this file, no other libraries are used, especially no native libraries. -

And some scary facts that I just refuse to believe to make any sense:

- Removing all class files and rebuilding the project sometimes (rarely) helps. The program (nested version) runs fast one or two times before becoming extremely slow again.
- Installing a new JVM always helps (every single time!) such that the (nested) program runs fast at least once! Installing a JDK counts as two because both the JDK-jre and the JRE-jre work fine at least once. Overinstalling a JVM does not help. Neither does rebooting. I haven't tried deleting/rebooting/reinstalling yet ...
- These are the only two ways I ever managed to get fast program runtimes for the nested program.

Questions:

- What may cause this performance drop for nested JVMs?
- What exactly do these methods do (pwrite0/force0)? -

Answer (score 0):

Are you using local disks for all testing (as opposed to any network share) ?

Can you setup Windows with a ram drive to store the data ?  When a JVM terminates, by default its file handles will have been closed but what you might be seeing is the flushing of the data to the disk.  When you overwrite lots of data the previous version of data is discarded and may not cause disk IO.  The act of closing the file might make windows kernel implicitly flush data to disk.  So using a ram drive would allow you to confirm that their since disk IO time is removed from your stats.

Find a tool for windows that allows you to force the kernel to flush all buffers to disk, use this in between JVM runs, see how long that takes at the time.

But I would guess you are hitten some iteraction with the demands of the process and the demands of the kernel in attempting to manage disk block buffer cache.  In linux there is a tool like "/sbin/blockdev --flushbufs" that can do this.

FWIW

"pwrite" is a Linux/Unix API for allowing concurrent writing to a file descriptor (which would be the best kernel syscall API to use for the JVM, I think Win32 API already has provision for the same kinds of usage to share a file handle between threads in a process, but since Sun have Unix heritige things get named after the Unix way).  Google "pwrite(2)" for more info on this API.

"force" I would guess that is a file system sync, meaning the process is requesting the kernel to flush unwritten data (that is currently in disk block buffer cache) into the file on the disk (such as would be needed before you turned your computer off).  This action will happen automatically over time, but transactional systems require to know when the data previously written (with pwrite) has actually hit the physical disk and is stored.  Because some other disk IO is dependant on knowing that, such as with transactional checkpointing.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that could help is making sure you explicitly set the `FileChannel` to `null`. Then call `System.runFinalization()` and maybe `System.gc()` at the end of the program. You may need more than 1 call.

`System.runFinalizersOnExit(true)` may also help, but it's deprecated so you will have to deal with the compiler warnings.