# What is the right way to close and/or delete a memory mapped file?

Tags: java, memory-mapped-files

From what I've read, it's a bit tricky closing a memory mapped file in Java.

By default, they're closed only by a mechanism akin to (but more efficient than) finalization.

I already know it's possible to close them explicitly in an implementation-specific way (but one common to both OpenJDK and the Oracle JDK) by using reflection, using the following code (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19447758/1055489) to a related question):

```
try {
    Method cleanerMethod = buffer.getClass().getMethod("cleaner");
    cleanerMethod.setAccessible(true);
    Object cleaner = cleanerMethod.invoke(buffer);
    Method cleanMethod = cleaner.getClass().getMethod("clean");
    cleanMethod.setAccessible(true);
    cleanMethod.invoke(cleaner);
} catch(Exception ex) { /* log exception */ }
```

I gather from the discussion in that question that it's not reliably possible to delete the backing file for a `MappedByteBuffer` without closing the buffer in this manner.

However, there are also other, related resources that must be closed: the `RandomAccessFile` and the `FileChannel` that were used to create the `MappedByteBuffer`.

Does the order in which these resources are closed matter? Are there any differences between the order in which they must be closed on Mac/Windows/Linux?

Ultimately, what I want to know how to do safely comes down to these two questions:

What is the correct way to close a MappedByteBuffer (and related resources) and ensure the backing file is saved?

Is there a way to close a MappedByteBuffer (and related resources) without accidentally causing it to write uncommitted changes to the disk, when the goal is to quickly delete the backing file?