# Java fastest byte array file write + ensure file handles are released

Tags: java, nio

I need to write lots of byte arrays sized from 1MB to 2MB to individual files. The data is always allocated as a byte[] (it is calculated) so I cannot use FileChannel.transferTo. After the write it should be guaranteed flushed to the disk.

Is this the fastest solution?

```
FileChannel channel =  new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();
ByteBuffer buffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, data.length);
buffer.put(data);
channel.force(false);
channel.close();
```

In my test-suite I see that the files sometimes are locked by the OS (or JVM) (java.io.File.delete() returns false) when I do a clean up. I'm concerned about the resources not getting released. People suggest using System.gc() and also some unsafe solutions, but maybe my program could hit a max limit? Should I be concerned? Will it be a problem allocating lots of memory mapped files? It is from the same thread so they will be closed before opening a new. Also my program must be able to delete these files.

Please also read [How to unmap a file from memory mapped using FileChannel in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972986/how-to-unmap-a-file-from-memory-mapped-using-filechannel-in-java)

Comment: Do some benchmarking to see what is fastest. Start with FileOutputStream.write() and see if you can do better with BufferedOutputStream, and so on. I wouldn't jump immediately to mmap'ed files.

Comment: Can you check who/what has the files locked? You can always use delete on exit (if the process is not running constantly)

Comment: I have benchmarked and FileOutputStream + BufferedOutputStream is slower. But I am concerned about the locked files.

Comment: A BufferedOutputStream will slow things down if you have all the byte array in memory and can write it all at once directly with the FileOutputStream.

Comment: Yes BufferedOutputStream doesn't help here.

Comment: For the sake of futility: have you tried to keep a reference to the RAF and close it to see if the results are different?

Comment: @efekctive, yes also tried that, same behaviour

Comment: @Stig then I would try querying the os to figure out who has the handle on the file before you continue. It should save you some wild guessing

Comment: @efekctive, I think this have been covered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972986/how-to-unmap-a-file-from-memory-mapped-using-filechannel-in-java. Okay the questions is not about deleting the file, but opening the file afterward (same problem)

Comment: Then you would still need to know who has the file handle

Comment: mapping is not very efficient in java if you do not keep the file open for a long time. Using a blocking write in that case is most likely the best option. (And if you fsync at the end it does not matter how fast your write anyway)