# FileOutputStream try-with-resources doesn't close file descriptor

Tags: java, windows, java-8, io

I have code that extracts some specific large (about 15k entries) binary serialized file archive to folder on disk.

```
public void extractExact(Path absolutePath, DoubleConsumer progressConsumer) throws IOException
{
    ...
    // Extract to file channel
    try (final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(absolutePath.toFile()))
    {
        PakExtractor.Extract(pakFile, Entry, fos.getChannel(), progressConsumer);
    }
 }
```

`extractExact` function calls for every entry in archive.

after this, if I try to call `Files.delete(<archive_file_path>)` method - I will get an exception:

> java.nio.file.FileSystemException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

I checked my archive file in Process Explorer search and it says that I have ~15k file openings by my java.exe (as many as the files in the archive)

this happens only in windows (jdk1.8.0_162). On Linux I don't have any problems with "zombie" opened files.

Comment: Could be some service in Windows, which is indexing/analyzing the files? Some desktop search indexing, antivirus, etc?

Comment: Maybe you need to call `fos.flush()` before the next call? It could be that there is still something to write.

Comment: Your try-with-resources usage is correct. I have many times observed Windows keeping a lock on a file for some seconds after it was closed by a program, even non-Java programs (but I am having trouble finding an existing Stack Exchange question about it).

Comment: But why this detour? Just use `try(FileChannel ch = FileChannel.open(absolutePath, StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.CREATE)) { … }`, no need for `.toFile()`, no need for `.getChannel()`. And if you want to delete the file right afterwards, you can specify `StandardOpenOption.DELETE_ON_CLOSE` right at the `open` call.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj I not sure because this happens on all windows machines (with or without antivirus). Anyway, Process Explorer shows that files used by java.exe.

Comment: @Sascha it does not make any sense, the problem is still there :(

Comment: @Holger thank you, code more fluent now :)

Comment: Can this thing happens because of I pass my channel as argument to another procedure?

Anyway, what I found: if I toggle breakpoint at exception and evaluate next code `((FileChannelImpl) fileChannel.fd.closed` result will be false, I think this is not normal

Comment: The breakpoint should be in the `finally`part of your `try`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally - we found the solution. Many thanks to @Netherwire. [FileChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) class have `map` method that does some implicit copy operations with file descriptors, so be careful when use it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972986/how-to-unmap-a-file-from-memory-mapped-using-filechannel-in-java) is more information.

Comment: I encountered scenarios where I used the `DELETE_ON_CLOSE` option mentioned in [my previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55710865/fileoutputstream-try-with-resouces-doent-close-file-descriptor?noredirect=1#comment98106303_55710865) together with `map`. The good thing about it, is, when there are still existing mappings preventing deletion at `close()` time, the file will get deleted when the mappings are cleaned or at JVM exit time as a last resort.