# Java - When does direct buffer released?

Tags: java, nio, bytebuffer, direct-buffer

Since it's out of jvm heap & gc, when does it released? Or, it remain until process termination?

I already checked:

- [how to garbage collect a direct buffer java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854398/how-to-garbage-collect-a-direct-buffer-java)
- [Deallocating Direct Buffer Native Memory in Java for JOGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496508/deallocating-direct-buffer-native-memory-in-java-for-jogl/)
- [ByteBuffer.allocate() vs. ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670862/bytebuffer-allocate-vs-bytebuffer-allocatedirect)

But all the answers are blur, none answered it explicitly, does there have a clear answer? At least for *Java 8* on *64-bit Linux*.

Comment: When the `ByteBuffer` is garbage collected, the finalizer will execute and release any underlying memory allocation.

Comment: Since you don't have the guarantee that it will be freed, I suggest you to take care of it by yourself, I stripped down the [`BufferUtils`](https://github.com/jMonkeyEngine/jmonkeyengine/blob/master/jme3-core/src/main/java/com/jme3/util/BufferUtils.java) class from JM3 for my projects, like [here](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/framework/BufferUtils.java), and until now it works flawless

Comment: @elect Yeah, some books also says it's for big & long-live buffers, thus the delay of allocation will have less impact. For small & short-live buffer, it's suggested not to use `direct buffer`, use `indirect buffer` instead.

Comment: If the resourse is going to be used by OpenGL, buffer must be indirect. If you pass an indirect one, jogl has to create the direct one underneath. So better if it is you creating that, so you can keep track of it.

Comment: @elect Ok, I will keep in mind of existence for such cases.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`DirectByteBuffer` does not use old Java finalizers. Instead, it uses internal `sun.misc.Cleaner` API. It creates new thread and stores a `PhantomReference` to every `DirectByteBuffer` created (except duplicates and slices which refer to the primary buffer). When the `DirectByteBuffer` becomes *phantom-reachable* (that is, no strong, soft or weak references to the byte buffer exist anymore) and garbage collector sees this, it adds this buffer to the `ReferenceQueue` which is processed by `Cleaner` thread. So three events should occur:

- `DirectByteBuffer` becomes phantom-reachable.
- Garbage collection is performed (in separate thread), `DirectByteBuffer` Java object is collected and an entry is added to the `ReferenceQueue`.
- Cleaner thread reaches this entry and runs the registered clean-up action (in this case, it's `java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.Deallocator` object), this action finally frees the native memory.

So in general you have no guarantee when it's freed. If you have enough memory in the Java heap, garbage collector may not be activated for a long time. Also even when it's phantom-reachable, Cleaner thread may need some time to reach this entry. It might be busy processing previous objects which also used the Cleaner API. Note however that partial work-around is implemented in JDK: if you create new `DirectByteBuffer` and allocated too much direct memory before, garbage collector might be called explicitly to enforce deallocation of previously abandoned buffers. See [`Bits.reserveMemory()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/nio/Bits.java#Bits.reserveMemory%28long%2Cint%29) (called from `DirectByteBuffer` constructor) for details.

Note that in Java-9 the internal `Cleaner` API was rectified and published for general use: now it's [`java.lang.ref.Cleaner`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.html). Reading the JavaDoc you may get more details how it works.