# Freeing memory wrapped with NewDirectByteBuffer

Tags: java, memory-management, java-native-interface, nio, free

I have a region of memory wrapped with JNI `NewDirectByteBuffer`. I would like to run free/release code in the cleaner of the `ByteBuffer`. Is there a way to do this or do I have to offer a custom free method that the user will have to call with the `ByteBuffer`?

**Edit**

To clarify, I allocated the memory myself and called `NewDirectByteBuffer` myself. I would like to know how I should coordinate the clean up with the cleaner.

Comment: In Java 8's DirectByteBuffer you could call the Cleaner.clean() method though it's not a public API, so use knowing it's not portable.

Comment: @PeterLawrey And that will call free() always? What if I need a other clean up function than free()?

Comment: It will do whatever is appropriate to free the memory. You don't have any evidence that that involves calling `free()`.

Comment: @EJP how does it know what is appropriate? `NewDirectByteBuffer` only takes a pointer and a length. There is no way to pass a free function pointer.

Comment: @PhilippeMarschall Because the code is written by the same guys that wrote the code that allocated it. I don't know why you're so fixated on the `free()` function.

Comment: @EJP I am the guy that the wrote the code who allocated the memory and I certainly did not write any part of the JVM. I am so fixated on the `fee()` function because I'm the one who allocated the memory in the first place. It is my responsibility to see it gets released.

Comment: So, you create a direct byte buffer object in C, and let JVM control its lifecycle? Maybe you should extend DirectByteBuffer and override the clean method?

Comment: @AlexCohn DirectByteBuffer is package scoped and can not be extended.

Comment: You are right, this [may be trickier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26777380/192373) than I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `JNI.newDirectByteBuffer`, you can and you should free the memory manually, and do you clean up work at the same time.

If you want it clean up automatically, what you need is monitor the object's life cycle. And if you only want to work with API and don't use reflection, you can use a `PhantomReference` with `ReferenceQueue`, and create a demon thread to polling the queue. Do your clean up work once the reference be in the reference queue.

Comment: Please read the question. I am not using `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect`, I am using `NewDirectByteBuffer` from JNI. Because `NewDirectByteBuffer` does not take a free function pointer the JVM has no way of knowing how to free the memory region. `free` may or may not be appropriate.

Comment: `NewDirectByteBuffer ` returns a jobject which is `DirectByteBuffer` type. So the solution is the same, but from change the cleaner to create a cleaner.

Comment: So how do you control which free function is called?

Comment: @PhilippeMarschall I have edited my answer. Because I have no JNI environment, I use reflection to mock `newDirectByteBuffer`. And use `Unsafe` like `DirectByteBuffer` do. The core idea is same, do the clean up work when the object collected by gc.

Comment: So you're saying there is no API or supported way to do this? Or any way that works reliably across Java versions or JVMs? Or even works with Java 9 and module checks enforced.