# Is there a memory leak issue with using JNA's Memory class?

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, java-native-interface, jna

I am in a position where I want to pass `byte[]` to a native method via JNA.  All the examples I've found about this sort of thing either use a `Memory` instance or use a directly-allocated `ByteBuffer` and then get a `Pointer` from that.

However, when I read the docs they say that underlying native memory -- which as I understand it is allocated "off the books" **outside of the JVM-managed heap** -- these Java objects consume only get freed when the objects' `finalize()` method is called.

But when that finalizer gets called has nothing to do with when the objects go out of scope.  They could hang around for a long time before the garbage collector actually finalizes them.  So any native memory they've allocated will stay allocated for an arbitrarily-long time after they go out of scope.  If they are holding on to a lot of memory and/or if there are lots of the objects it would seem to me you have an effective memory leak.  Or least will have a steady-state memory consumption potentially a lot higher than it would seem to need to be.  In other words, similar behavior to what's described in  [JNA/ByteBuffer not getting freed and causing C heap to run out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744533/jna-bytebuffer-not-getting-freed-and-causing-c-heap-to-run-out-of-memory)

Is there any way around this problem with JNA?  Or will I need to give up on JNA for this and use JNI instead so that I can use `JNIEnv::GetByteArrayElements()` so there's no need for any "off the books" memory allocations that can persist arbitrarily long?  Is it acceptable to subclass `Memory` in order to get access to the `dispose()` method and use that to free up the underlying native memory on my timeline instead of the GC's timeline?  Or will that cause problems when the finalizer does run?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it - the garbage collector will be invoked whenever the heap is full and more memory is attempted to be allocated, so it only runs when it needs to.

Comment: The problem, as I understand it is that this kinds of objects take up minimal GC-managed-heap space but can take up significantly more unmanaged *process* memory space.  So the *process* can be taking up lots of memory before the GC sees enough heap "pressure" to go finalizing things.  See the link I've added in the main question description.

Comment: Ah yes.. according to a link on the page you linked, it's a [known bug](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4469299), open since 2001, still not resolved. I suppose the short answer to your question is 'yes'. One final suggestion: instead of regularly calling `System.gc()` as suggested in the workarounds, you could call it from your native code if `malloc` fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JNA provides `Memory.disposeAll()` and `Memory.dispose()` to explicitly free memory (the latter requires you to subclass `Memory`), so if you *do* ever encounter memory pressure for which regular GC is not sufficient, you have some additional control available.